# ASP.NET stripe.net Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe.net

```
 protected void ChargePayment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StripeCustomer CurrentCustomer = GetCustomer();

        if (CurrentCustomer == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        var myCharge = new StripeChargeCreateOptions();


        myCharge.Currency = "dkk";
        myCharge.CustomerId = CurrentCustomer.Id;
        myCharge.Description = "KPHF Prorated Charge";

        string key = "sk_test_P6GjMq1OVwmxZv5YNozAX6dY";
        var chargeService = new StripeChargeService(key);

        try
        {
            chargeService.Create(myCharge);

        }
        catch (StripeException ex)
        {
            exError.Text = ex.Message;
        }


    }

    private StripeCustomer GetCustomer()
    {
        MembershipUser CurrentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        var myCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();
        var myCustomer2 = new StripeCreditCardOptions();

        myCustomer.Email = cMail.Text;
        myCustomer2.TokenId = CreditCard.Text;
        myCustomer2.ExpirationMonth = CardMonth.SelectedItem.Text;
        myCustomer2.ExpirationYear = CardYear.SelectedItem.Text;
        myCustomer2.Cvc = cvc.Text;

        myCustomer.PlanId = "1";


        var customerService = new StripeCustomerService("sk_test_P6GjMq1OVwmxZv5YNozAX6dY");

        try
        {
            StripeCustomer result = customerService.Create(myCustomer);

            return result;
        }
        catch (StripeException ex)
        {
            exError.Text = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
```

After entering credit card info I do get customer created in the stripe system, but he's not being charged and I get following exception: "Cannot charge a customer that has no active card". Any help or tips?

Answer (score 6):

you are not attaching the card with the customer. You have created the card object but not attached with the customer. Follow this syntax to add the card

```
var myCustomer = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();
    myCustomer.Email = "pork@email.com";
    myCustomer.Description = "Johnny Tenderloin (pork@email.com)";

    // setting up the card
    myCustomer.SourceCard = new SourceCard()
    {
        Number = "4242424242424242",
        ExpirationYear = "2022",
        ExpirationMonth = "10",
        Cvc = "1223"                          // optional
    };

    myCustomer.PlanId = *planId*;                          // only if you have a plan
    myCustomer.TaxPercent = 20;                            // only if you are passing a plan, this tax percent will be added to the price.
    myCustomer.Coupon = *couponId*;                        // only if you have a coupon
    myCustomer.TrialEnd = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);    // when the customers trial ends (overrides the plan if applicable)
    myCustomer.Quantity = 1;                               // optional, defaults to 1

    var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
    StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = customerService.Create(myCustomer)
```

you can read more about it here [stripe .net](https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net)

Comment: @ŽeniaBogdasic, If the answer fulfilled your requirement, you should accept to help other viewers as its a perfect solution in respective case.

Comment: It's Working. Thanks